# use RTMPE url in NGINX

Tags: nginx, jwplayer

I want to show a video on jwplayer with rtmpe url. how can I config nginx to rtmpe? is this possible to use rtmpe in nginx or nginx plus?
if it is not possible then would you please offer me a way to use rtmpe url in jwplayer?
thanks

Comment: thanks for your response. I decided to use wowza streaming engine. but some how I don't know how to add jwplayer to that.

Comment: If you are using Wowza, here is how to do this as far as JW Player goes - http://support.jwplayer.com/customer/en/portal/articles/1430349-about-rtmp-streaming, http://support.jwplayer.com/customer/en/portal/articles/1430358-using-rtmp-streaming

Comment: thanks, I tried it before. now the problem is to use rtmpe

Comment: I would ask Wowza about that.